# Peer-Peer communication using wi-fi in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to send a message from one android device to another through `Wi-Fi`.

I have two android devices , and `Portable wifi Hotspot` is enabled on both. I developed an application which displays a list of availabe `wifi devices` , and both of the devices lists each other.

Now I want to connect both and send a text from one device to another. What I know is that wifi transmitters transmit a beacon frame , which contains `SSID` , `BSSID` etc.

What should I do ? Should I apply a socket operation , but I don't have `IP address`.

Comment: I've done a quick Google Search, but all the links I've found seem to be absolutely useless, so I'm upvoting this.  I know it can be done; there are Android apps that talk to your computer over wifi.  If anyone can provide a reasonably comprehensive answer on how this is accomplished, I'll stick a bounty on it.

Comment: Are the two devices connected to the same wifi router, or can they be anywhere in the world?

Comment: The two devices are in the range of each other

Comment: What is the minSDK Android version number that your Android application needs to support? This is a real important question. Your minimum requirements will dictate what features are available to you. Also, is there a reason you've ruled out Bluetooth? And finally, what kind of application is this, something you will install on Google Play, or something for enterprise where you can dictate the kind of devices will be used?

Comment: By the way, turning on the Portable Wifi Hotspot for both devices is the wrong approach. They will both be using their own local wifi networks if you do that. You should just turn on one hotspot wifi network and have the other phone connect to it. This way, they'll each have their own IP address in the same subnet and they should be able to talk to each other. If that doesn't work, have both both phones (with the hotspot turned off) login into your home wifi network (just don't do this at work, in a coffee shop, or in a hotel, where for security reasons, local wifi isolation may be turned on)

Comment: It would interesting to know how did he managed to see each other while in hotspot mode, AFAIK this is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done this so I can't provide code, but the answer is to use wifi- direct.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html.  That allows you to discover devices on wifi with you, then send data to them via normal sockets.

There is a wifi-direct sample app with the SDK.

Comment: Not comprehensive enough to warrant a bounty, but believe it or not, this is apparently the most useful answer on the internet so far.

Comment: That's... rather sad, since my sum total knowledge of the service is that it exists and what its supposed to do.  I've never had the need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung recently released a simple API intended to make P2P apps easier to build - http://developer.samsung.com/chord

It only works on Android 4.0 and up, but it appears that is also the case with Wi-Fi Direct.

Comment: no, it does not. It requires touchwiz which is Samsung's proprietary user interface.

Comment: My initial impression was also that it was only for TouchWiz-enabled devices, but this appears to be misinformation from news articles. A TouchWiz requirement isn't mentioned anywhere on the Chord SDK documentation. Quite the opposite - the documentation states "Chord will extend Samsung’s sharing presence beyond our own proprietary platform into the developer ecosystem." I've successfully run the SDK sample app on and transferred files via Wi-Fi between a Nexus 4 emulator, Galaxy Nexus, and Galaxy S3.

Comment: Yes and no. It does work with the latest Nexus 4 (which is made by LG, the arch-enemy of Samsung). It also works with the stock non-Touchwiz Nexus S and the stock non-Touchwiz Galaxy Nexus branded by Google (but made by Samsung). And their documentation does state that they hope that it will eventually work on all devices (even non-Samsung devices and even older devices). It's just that this is not done yet. Also, you have to keep in mind this new Chord API just came out 2 months ago. Their Eclipse Chord-specific plugin/emulator to simulate multiple connections didn't work for me.