# Is it possible to list other access points while being a hotspot?

Tags: android, wireless

There are numerous good answers how to enable hotspot in code on Android devices. However, the WifiManager thinks that Wi-Fi is disabled in that time and therefore this:

```
mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();

// Register broadcast receiver 
// Broacast receiver will automatically call when number of wifi connections changed
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
mainWifi.startScan();
```

never calls WifiReceiver::onReceive() (I tested that while hotspot is inactive, the method is called, i.e. the code is working). I'd perhaps consider this as a fact but then I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642632/peer-peer-communication-using-wi-fi-in-android) where the author claims he was able to create two hotspots and they saw each other. Unfortunately, without code. How something like this could have been done?

Answer (score 0):

When a device is a hotspot, it doesn't connect to another hotspot. You either use wifi to connect to a hotspot, or you use it to be a hotspot. 
When the hotspot is enabled, as you say "wifimanager thinks wifi is disabled", that's because it can't use wifi to connect to another hotspot.

Comment: But I'm talking about listing/discovering/scanning. I'm interested merely in scan results. Just to see what's nearby.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get scan results when your device is a hotspot. In order to get scan results, the device needs to scan for hotspots, acting like a wifi client itself. It's been about a year since I built an app doing wifi hotspots and scans, I'd have to look through the code, but I'm pretty sure you can't scan and be a hotspot at the same time.